# Prove $x^{x^x} \equiv x^x \mod 16$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$x^{x^x} \equiv x^x \pmod{16}$
Prove by a simple and (quite an) elementary proof that the expression above is true for every $x>2$ ($x$ is a natural number).
The question does not have a topic and you can use **any basic tool** to answer it. I tried using Modulo first, but couldn't quite get the result. I also thought we might have to use the Euler function but I couldn't find the context. I'd be very happy if anyone could give me a clue, direction or a partial solution. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried using Modulo first", precisely?

Comment: @The Demonix _ Hermit
I checked for 3 and 4....

Comment: This is equivalent to showing that 
$$
x^{x^x - x} \equiv 1 \pmod{16}
$$

Comment: @user3482749 I tried using Modulo

Comment: @Omnomnomnom
I know that

Comment: @1212duks His point is that "tried using Modulo" is not enough information for us to figure out what you actually did

Comment: @The Demonix _ Hermit It's also true for all even numbers of course.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I really think what I did is not even in the direction, so I ask for a clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've stated, the statement for even $x > 2$ is trivial.

Your statement for the odd $x$ is equivalent to showing that for all odd $x \geq 3$, we have
$$
\frac{x^{x^x}}{x^x} \equiv x^{x(x^{x-1} - 1)} \equiv 1 \pmod {16}.
$$
By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), it suffices to show that for odd $x \geq 3$, $(x^{x-1} - 1)$ is divisible by $8$, which is to say that
$$
x^{x-1} \equiv 1 \pmod8.
$$
As it turns out, every odd $x$ satisfies $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, and it follows that the above (and thus your statement) holds.

---

Another approach: to show that $(x^{x-1} - 1)$ is divisible by $8$, take $x = 2n+1$ to find that
$$
x^{x-1} - 1 = ((2n+1)^{n})^2 - 1 = ((2n+1)^n - 1)((2n+1)^n + 1).
$$
Since $(2n+1)^n$ is odd, the numbers $(2n+1)^n \pm 1$ must consist of one multiple of $2$ and one multiple of $4$.  Thus, their product $x^{x-1} - 1$ is indeed divisible by $8$.

Comment: Wow! that's awsome. Thank you so much! Your solution is so simple and beautiful :)